# How do I use polymorhism for lists in swiftUI?

Tags: swift, list, swiftui, swift-protocols

I want to add two different types, Pig and Frog, to the same array. Normally this would work well as long as both conform to the same protocol. However, in `swiftUI` if you want to use that `array` for a `List` then those types also need to conform to `Identifiable`. Like so:

```
protocol Animal: Identifiable {
    var id: String { get }
    var name: String { get }
    var count: Int { get }
    var image: String { get }
}

struct Pig: Animal {
    var id: String = UUID().uuidString
    
    var name = "Pig"
    var count = 2
    var image = ""
}

struct Frog: Animal {
    var id: String = UUID().uuidString
    
    var name = "Frog"
    var count = 3
    var image = ""
}

struct ContentView: View {
    var animals: [Animal] = [Pig(), Frog()]

    var body: some View {
        List(animals) { animal in
            Row(animals: animal)
        }
    }
}
```

This gives me the error `Protocol 'Animal' can only be used as a generic constraint because it has Self or associated type requirements`.

So my questions are why is this a problem and how do I get around it?
I experimented a bit and tried using an associated type like this:

```
protocol ConstructAnimal: View where AnimalType: Animal {
    associatedtype AnimalType
    
    var animals: [AnimalType] { get set }
}
```

But this still only lets me have one type in the `array` at a time.

Comment: You don't need `Identifiable` for a `List` if you use the `id` parameter. `List(animals, id: \.name)`. Just make sure you use a property that is unique as the argument.

Comment: What Swift version are you using? The debugger should hint you the usage of `any`.